# How to stop Steam from cluttering /var/log/syslog?

Tags: steam, 17.10, logging

I just installed Steam on a freshly installed 17.10 with vanilla gnome desktop on Xorg. now I have the following happening, when starting Steam (which works fine btw) I get the following entry in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 23 23:07:29 NEXUS-ONE org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1628]: process 3698: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2824.
Oct 23 23:07:29 NEXUS-ONE org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1628]: This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
```

This same line gets added to `syslog` about 6 times per second as long Steam is running, growing the `syslog` for about 60 MB per 18 hours.

Already checked the configs in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` but saw nothing unusual, in fact they are untouched since installation.

Already filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/steam/+bug/1726083) on the steam package, but until this gets fixed heres my question, how can I stop this cluttering while still running Steam?